# sender inside a future

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor which on receiving a message, searches the filesystem for a file and returns the full path of the File.

To keep it asynchronous, I have done:

```
def receive = {
  case s:String => {

    val f = future{
      val ans = search(s)
      println("Input Request: "+s+" output:"+ans+" "+sender.path)
    }
    f.onComplete{
      case Success(x) => sender ! x
      case Failure(y) => println("Could not complete it")
    }
  } 
}
```

But I have observed that it returns the message to `akka://FileSystem/deadLetters` and not the `sender`. Documentation says that:

> Only valid within the Actor itself, so do not close over it and
>      * publish it to other threads!

So does it mean, I will have to necessarily keep it synchronous? Is there any other way?

Comment: Why use a future? It's an I/O operation (and so possibly blocking), so put the actor on the blocking-io dispatcher. If you need to search for multiple files at once, have multiple instances running.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are making a very common mistake of "closing over mutable state".  The closure you pass to `onComplete` does not make a copy of `this.sender`, so when your `onComplete` gets called, you are sending the message to whatever `this.sender` happens to point to at that time, not what it pointed to when you created the closure.

You can avoid this problem by creating your own local, immutable copy of the current contents of `this.sender`, and reference that value in the closure:

```
val origSender = sender
f.onComplete {
    case Successs(x) => origSender ! x
    ...
}
```

Comment: is this necessary for `self` as well ?

Comment: @GeorgePligor No, self is not mutable.

Answer (score 3):

```
import akka.pattern.pipe
```

Does the trick. Doing:

```
val reply = sender
future {
  val ans = searchAndCache(s)
  println("Input Request: "+s+" output:"+ans+" "+reply.path)
  ans
} pipeTo reply
```

replies back to the sender

Comment: It seems like this answer incorrectly or misleadingly focuses on pipeTo. As far as I know, using pipeTo instead of ! didn't fix the problem. Saving the sender in "reply" is what would prevent the behavior that you were seeing before, which is what stew's answer focuses on.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I've got to add this, 
the **pipeTo** is the right way but **you don't need to copy your sender**, 
 
you're already in the same context.
 
actually the pipeTo does this for you.
 
it will take the current sender ref (by passing to it's argument)
 
and use it to resolve the future for you (look at it's implementation)
 
just do:

```
future {
  val ans = searchAndCache(s)
  println("Input Request: "+s+" output:"+ans+" "+reply.path)
  ans
} pipeTo reply
```