# Akka ask returns nothing when tell is used in future

Tags: scala, akka

The following code uses 2 asks and initially seems like it supposed to print **"This should be printed in actor1 but most of the time wont because of a race condition with the receive method finishing"**.
However there seems to be a race condition between the 'receive' method finishing and the future finishing and thus nothing is printed.
Is this the intended behavior by akka? is this a bug?
I am trying to avoid using 'ask' as much as possible and using 'tell' instead, but sometimes it's a must.

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.routing.SmallestMailboxPool
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object ActorsAskingStuff extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("abc-system")
  val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[Actor1].withRouter(SmallestMailboxPool(1)), "actor1")
  actor1 ! 5
}

class Actor1 extends Actor {
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(60 seconds)
  val actor2: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[Actor2].withRouter(SmallestMailboxPool(1)), "actor2")
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ =>
      println("actor1 was called")
      actor2 ? "hello" onComplete {
      case Success(a) => println(a)
      case Failure(b) => println("FAILURE")
    }
  }
}

class Actor2 extends Actor {
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(6 seconds)
  val actor3: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[Actor3].withRouter(SmallestMailboxPool(1)), "actor3")
  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case _ =>
      println("actor2 was called")
      actor3 ? "hello" map {
        _ =>
          println("Actor2 completed the future")
          sender ! "This should be printed in actor1 but most of the time wont because of a race condition with the receive method finishing"
      }

      // uncomment this to make it work
      //Thread.sleep(100)
  }
}

class Actor3 extends Actor {
  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case _ =>
      println("actor3 was called")
      sender ! "I'm actor3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the JVM shutting down before the actor messages get processed? Try sleeping for a while at the end of `ActorsAskingStuff`.

Comment: Not really. I think running an actor system prevents it from shutting down. Event if I add sleep it doesn't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing over the `sender` when you do this:

```
actor3 ? "hello" map {
  _ =>
    println("Actor2 completed the future")
    sender ! "This should be printed in actor1 but most of the time wont because of a race condition with the receive method finishing"
}
```

At that point the `sender` could have changed.  In order to avoid closing over the `sender` you can rewrite like this:

```
val originator = sender()
actor3 ? "hello" map {
  _ =>
    println("Actor2 completed the future")
    originator ! "This should be printed in actor1 but most of the time wont because of a race condition with the receive method finishing"
}
```

Once you go into a `Future` based callback (like `onComplete` or `map` for example) at that point, the actor thinks it's done precessing the current message and moves onto the next message in the mailbox (if there is one).  When this happens, the `sender()` which is just a def that returns the value of a `var` that is subject to change will return either a new `ActorRef` (more messages) or nothing (deadletter) if no messages.

You can checkout this post for more info:
[sender inside a future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898131/sender-inside-a-future)

Comment: Thanks seems to work this out! I'm guessing it works that way because the sender saves the state of the current actor I'm talking with and because the recieve method finished it could be a different actor?

Comment: Ok the last part of your answer cleared this up.
Thanks again! Would upvote if could

Comment: @Monadsarelike... you should still be able to accept the answer even though you can not upvote.