# Test AKKA actors that dependant on the future

Tags: scala, testing, concurrency, akka, future

I'm trying to write a simple test for an actor that depends on the Future. Here's pretty much self explanatory code

```
import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorSystem, Props }
import akka.testkit.{ ImplicitSender, TestKit }
import org.scalatest.{ BeforeAndAfterAll, WordSpecLike }

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

trait Provider {def get(s: String): Future[String] }

class MyActor(provider: Provider) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case s: String ⇒
      provider.get(s) map { result: String ⇒
        sender() ! result
      }
  }
}

class FutureTest
  extends TestKit(ActorSystem("Test"))
    with ImplicitSender
    with WordSpecLike
    with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  "MyActor" must {
    "wait for the future" in {
      val myref = system.actorOf(Props(
        new MyActor((s) ⇒ Future { s })
      ))

      myref ! "hello world"

      expectMsg("hello world")
    }
  }
}
```

Expect msg won't wait for the future to get completed and fails with the following message:

`assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for hello world
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for hello world`

What is the best practice to test this sort of behaviour in my case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never close over `sender()` in a callback passed to a future. See this SO question for why and how to fix:

[sender inside a future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898131/sender-inside-a-future)