# Scala / Akka: How actor keeps the command and changes the behavior to execute it

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-persistence

I would like to stash the received message and migrate the data after the success of the migration I change the behavior to execute the stashed command.

```
trait Actor { this: Stash with Actor =>
   def executeCommands: Receive = {
     case "OK" => sender ! "ok"
     case _ => sender ! "false"
 }

  def migrateData(): Future[Unit Or Error] = Future.successful(Good(()))

   override def receive: Receive ={
      case _ =>
            stash()
            migrateData().map {
             case Good(_) =>
               context.become(executeCommands)
               unstashAll()
            case Bad(err) =>
              unstashall()
              sender ! err
  }   } }
```

I recive an exception 
`` AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$defaultOnTimeout$1(AskSupport.scala:646)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$apply$1(AskSupport.scala:667)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$7.run(Scheduler.scala:476) ``

Comment: sender reference might have changed in case if your migrateData is returning a future.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898131/sender-inside-a-future

Comment: @ShankarShastri I pass the sender as argument in the method def handleCommands(sender: ActorRef): Receive before the execution of the migrateData but I have the same result an exception

Comment: can you update the code changes? And what's the timeout on the ask that you are passing?